# Logstash filter with more matcher

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I want to define a logstash filter with than one matcher because in one .log file there is more type of logged message.
As I checked if I have one logfile and I define more separated filter then just the first filter running on the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `grok` filter with multiple patterns, or you can use `if` statements to conditionally parse.

To use multiple patterns, you'd just list them on the `grok`:

```
grok {
  match => [ "message", 
     "Error on line (?<line>\d+)",
     "Exception in (?<place>\d+)",
     "Something else"
  ]
}
```

Logstash will evaluate them in order and stop when one of them matches (or give you a tag of `_grokparsefailure` if none match)

The other thing you can do is conditional evaluation:

```
if [message] =~ /Some pattern/ {
   grok {
     match => ['message','Some pattern of (?<number>\d+) stuff']
   }
} else if [message] =~ /Some other pattern/ {
  ...
}
```